# Multiple requests issue with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a multi-tab feature incorporated with ajax calls.

**show.html.erb**

`<a href="#tabs-2A<%= id %>"> # dynamically generated tabs within loop`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/controller1/method1",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {  },
    success: function (html) {
        $(element).find("#id").append(html);
    }
});
```

OnClick on any these tabs triggers ajax call. note: I have used `append` above.

**partial** which is getting appended, similar to actual one

```
<td><input type="checkbox" data-some_id="<%= @object.id %>", id="dots"/></td>
```

JS.

```
$('body').on("click", "#dots", function(){
   $.ajax({
    var some_id = $(".dot-checked").data('some_id');
    type: "GET",
    url: "/controller1/method2",
    dataType: "json",
    .....
   });
});
```

So you can see there is ajax call within this partial.

Everything works fine.

But,

I'm running into multiple requests issue(onclick for *checkbox*), when you click on a same tab multiple times or even if we click on other tabs.

It's because of script that is getting appended every time for **partial** page request.

Number of duplicate requests(/controller1/method2) is equal to number of times tab is clicked.

How do I get over this?

If it's not clear, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is to prevent the checkbox from being clicked twice when an AJAX call is in progress. Since you're working with a checkbox, it's usually better to use the `change` event handler, rather than `click`. This method will disable the checkbox until the AJAX call is complete.

```
$("#dots").on("change", function(){
   $(this).prop('disabled', true); // disable on click/change
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "controller/method",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function() {
        $('#dots').prop('disabled', false); // re-enable after AJAX is complete
     }
   });
});
```